# Django/Postgres: Choose from DISTINCT ON sets

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, distinct, django-orm

I have these models:

```
class Product(Model):
    ...

class Scanning(Model):
    product = ForeignKey(..)
    datetime = DateTimeField(...)
    ...
```

I'm trying to get one scanning for each product where the scanning is a latest one from `product.scanning.all()` set.

```
s1 = (product1,01.01.1000)
s2 = (product2,01.01.1200)
s3 = (product1,01.01.1900)
s4 = (product2,01.01.1988)
s5 = (product3,01.01.2015)
s6 = (product3,01.01.1970)
```

would return `<s4,s3,s5>`

```
Scanning.objects.filter(product__user=u,product__active=True).distinct('product_id').order_by('datetime')
```

Raises exception:

> ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial
>   ORDER BY expressions LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON
>   ("productapp_scanning"."product_id") "pro...
>                               ^

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With postgres, you cannot do `distinct` on a field, unless it's also what you sort by:

```
Scanning.objects.filter(product__user=u,product__active=True).distinct('product_id').order_by('product_id', 'datetime')
```

If that's not good enough, one solution is to make a double query like this:

```
q1 = Scanning.objects.filter(product__user=u,product__active=True).values('product_id').distinct().annotate(x=Max('id'))

q2 = Scanning.objects.filter(id__in=[i["x"] for i in q1])
```